# \NP macro as in P=NP formula, to work for both text and math modes

Tags: math-mode, bold, italic, text-mode

I want `\NP` command to produce the string "NP" in both text and math (e.g. P=NP formula) modes. I also want it to be styled (even if it is in math mode) the same as the surrounding text (italic or bold if the surrounding text is italic or bold).

Comment: `\text{NP}` will take on the surrounding style. Uses `amsmath`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `amsmath`, the command `\text` will take on the surrounding style.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\NP}{\text{NP}}

\begin{document}

We have \NP. \emph{To emphasize, we have \NP}. \textbf{In bold we have \NP}.

\textit{Here is italic text with math $\text{P}=\NP$.}

Here is upright text with math $\text{P}=\NP$.

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you do **not** want this, use `\textup` instead of `\text`. This will still show up as bold in a header, but not be italicized in a theorem statement.